# I created a webpage which is not working as it's suppose to on GitHub

Tags: github, button

I created a webpage (which is linked to an external website) and uploaded it on GitHub. There's a button which when clicked will take you to the external website but it's not working on GitHub.

My website is https://iamdaniel1612.github.io/

The code is at https://github.com/iamdaniel1612/iamdaniel1612.github.io

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't even know where to begin.
That's why...